# How to match a CriteriaBuilder Predicate with a given Entity?

Tags: criteria-api

In my use case I have the following setup: A Contract has a Person and a Provider associated. Therefore the contract has a foreign key on the persons table and the providers table. So in CriteriaApi I made a join over Contract and Person and Provider:

```
Root<Contract> contract = ...
Join <Contract, Person> person = contract.join(Person.class);
Join <Contract, Provider> provider = contract.join(Provider.class);
```

Building predicates which check for certain values in a person works perfectly well, e.g.

```
cb.like(person.get(Person_.lastname), lastname);
```

For the provider the situation is different because I already have the ProviderEntity to join on. But I did not find a way to tell CriteriaApi something in the way of

```
cb.is(provider.get(Provider_), provider);
```

It seems kind of stupid to search for the provider based on some field if I already have the Entity including the primary key (which in turn is not mapped in Provider_).

Since I'm working in the context of Spring Data I can only define the Specification and not the full query, by the way. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, maybe I should just delete the question because I realized how stupid it is. I will leave it for now so somebody might learn from it :-)

Instead of building the Predicate on the Join I can just do it on the Root like

```
cb.equal(contract.get(Contract_.provider), provider);
```